# How to cache cloudfront response sometime with a specific header and sometime without taking account the headers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Apigateway with a Cloudfront distribution. I've setup a custom Authorizer. The distribution is configured to forward the whitelisted header `Authorization`.

As an example, i've got 2 urls:

- `http://domain.tld/me` (the logged in user informations)
- `http://domain.tld/products` (the products collection)

The goal is to cache `/products` but **not based** on `Authorization` header. On the other side, I would like `/me` to be cached with `Authorization` header (because **I don't want user B get cached information from user A**). The both urls are protected with the authorizer.

How can i do that ?

Comment: If Authorization is not required for requests with path /products, you can simply have two cache behaviors, one with /products(no Authorization whitelisted) and /me (Authorization header whitelisted),  based on your requirement, "The goal is to cache /products but not based on Authorization header": if Authorization really required for /products request, you can add it in origin custom header with some value because anyway requests will be served from cache.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to authenticate a request based on the `Authorization` header before allowing them to see `/products` yet you don't want the object to be cached based on the `Authorization` header, then you can't use CloudFront with an API Gateway custom authorizer, because there is no way for CloudFront to pass a header through without caching on it -- such a configuration doesn't make sense, because CloudFront wouldn't know whether the request should be authorized at all.

One workaround is to use a Lambda@Edge Viewer Request trigger instead of a custom authorizer, to allow/disallow access to CloudFront on the `/products` path based on `Authorization`.  If a Viewer Request trigger returns control to CloudFront (rather that emitting its own internally-generated response) then the cache is checked and the response served from the cache (hit) or fetched from the origin (miss).  The header doesn't need to be whitelisted in order to be accessible to a viewer request trigger.

If the backend requires a generic authentication token for a path that doesn't vary based on user, then CloudFront can inject that using Custom Origin Headers.

Comment: If you were me, what would you do ?